# How to connect the camera with sencha touch?

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm doing a project with sencha touch, but I need to connect the camera iPad to take a picture. The development is via web. Please help me, I find not a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't believe you can do that with the Sencha Touch framework, but to be honest it has been over a year since I've used it so the APIs may have changed.

Comment: Thanks Brian. The development is via WEB, but with a native look and feel. Can do in Objective-C classes and access to Sencha Touch iPAD camera? If so, how does the link from a web server? Please help me.

Comment: Sorry, that is not possible. A web application cannot access native APIs. Only a native application can do that.

Comment: You can access camera or other devices directly from a web browser using html5. Please have a look [here...](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

Comment: This has been possible for a while, just google for a tut.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the documentation: "Sencha Touch enables you to quickly and easily create HTML5 based **mobile apps**".

So if you are building an mobile application, you can check the [Ext.device.Camera](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.device.Camera) API of Sencha Touch 2.  Alternatively, you may also want to consider a project like [Apache Cordova](http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/) (formely PhoneGap) and the camera object.

If you are not building an application but a "standard" web site, Sencha Touch will not help.  Particularly, a web site cannot call native device feature.

Comment: Thanks Gaëtan, the development of the application I'm doing is via WEB, can you connect the iPAD camera, take the picture and display it in HTML5?

Comment: @hekomobile Changed the answer to make clear Sencha Touch is for mobile applications.  From a web site, you cannot access device native features.

Comment: The development is via WEB, but with a native look and feel. Can do in Objective-C classes and access to Sencha Touch iPAD camera? If so, how does the link from a web server? Please help me someone. This.

Answer (score -2):

The answers to this post are out of date for anyone reading this after Q2 2013.

You can do this on a mobile website now.